# Revert ssh from publickey to password

Tags: ssh

I operated a debian server for a while while just by permitting a publickey-based access. Unfortunately I lost the private key (reinstall without backup), and now I am not able to log into the system anymore. I am able to access the hard drive, thus I can modify data on the hard disk. I already reverted the `sshd_config`-file, but I still get the error when trying to log in via ssh:

```
Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

What do I have to enable in the `sshd_config`-file in order to enable password-based access again?

sshd_config:

```
Port 234
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
Banner /etc/issue.net
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM no
```

Comment: Did you restart the `ssh` service on the host after modifying the configuration?

Comment: Also verify the setting of `PasswordAuthentication`, if omitted, defaults to `yes`.

Comment: @Lambert: The PC was shut down during change, thus I assume that the service did restart

Comment: Ensure you don't have a match rule that applies to your user and/or group.

Comment: @BitsOfNix: How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe include the whole of the sshd_config in the question (with comments removed to reduce the size) to prevent us asking about lots of config settings.  Something like `egrep -v "#|^$" /etc/ssh/sshd_config` should do it, it's usually quite short (20-40 lines).

Comment: @EightBitTony: Done

Comment: You might have a client configuration which only allows the use of key authentication. Can you verify the content of `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @Lambert: That file does not exist

Comment: Can you check the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client?

Comment: @Lambert: Should I paste it here, excluding the comments?

Comment: Please update the question with the information (excluding comment lines).

Answer (score 1):

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then set this line to:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Bringing the OS up will refresh the service and reload openssh configuration.

Comment: This did not work, I still get `publickey ` as onliest auth method